# train_test_split - Cannot operate on Dask array with unknown chunk sizes

Tags: python, dask, dask-ml

I have a text classification dataset where I used dask parquet to save disk space, but run into the problem now when I want to split the dataset into train and test using `dask_ml.model_selection.train_test_split`.

```py
ddf = dd.read_parquet('/storage/data/cleaned')
y = ddf['category'].values
X = ddf.drop('category', axis=1).values
train, test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
```

Resulting in 
`TypeError: Cannot operate on Dask array with unknown chunk sizes.`

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What happens if your drop all the `.values`?

Comment: And just out of curiosity, have you formed the parquet file from CSV? If so, I would be happy to hear how you did it.

Comment: @InonPeled you can convert a csv file to parquet with dask like `dd.read_csv('file.csv').repartition(npartitions=10).to_parquet('your_parquet_directory')`. The number of partitions are up to you, but it is recommended to have the file size around 100MB.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I ended up doing for the time being:

```py
ddf = dd.read_parquet('/storage/data/cleaned')
ddf = ddf.to_dask_array(lengths=True)
train, test = train_test_split(ddf, test_size=0.2)
```

This will create a dask.array of some shape `dask.array<array, shape=(3937987, 2), dtype=object, chunksize=(49701, 2)>`